# Conversion of dates in the dataframe column into MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 dataframes named `df1`,`df2`,`df3`,`df4` with one column `Date`. The column consist of dates with different format. `df1` has date column of type int64, `df2` has date column of type object, `df3` has date column has type object, `df4` has date column of type object. Below are the dataframe and its data.

```
df1:
          Date
0     20160301
1     20160301
2     20160301
3     20160301

df2: 
      Date
0   01/03/2016
1   01/03/2016
2   01/03/2016

df3:
      Date
0   31-Mar-16
1   31-Mar-16
2   31-Mar-16

df4:
      Date
0  25/02/2016
1  25/02/2016
2  25/02/2016
```

I want to convert these dates in the form as `mm/dd/yyyy` of type `date`. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), but `type` is not `datetime`, but `string`:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df3['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df4['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df4['Date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print df1
print df2
print df3
print df4
         Date
0  03/01/2016
1  03/01/2016
2  03/01/2016
3  03/01/2016
         Date
0  01/03/2016
1  01/03/2016
2  01/03/2016
         Date
0  03/31/2016
1  03/31/2016
2  03/31/2016
         Date
0  02/25/2016
1  02/25/2016
2  02/25/2016

print type(df1.at[0,'Date'])
<type 'str'>
```

If you want `datetime`, format is `YY-MM-DD`:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df3['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date'])
df4['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df4['Date'])

print df1
print df2
print df3
print df4
        Date
0 2016-03-01
1 2016-03-01
2 2016-03-01
3 2016-03-01
        Date
0 2016-01-03
1 2016-01-03
2 2016-01-03
        Date
0 2016-03-31
1 2016-03-31
2 2016-03-31
        Date
0 2016-02-25
1 2016-02-25
2 2016-02-25

print type(df1.at[0,'Date'])
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

More info about formating `datetime` is [here](http://strftime.org/).

Comment: I think in `df1` and `df2` is unclear, if first are days or months in string. Is correct my solution ?